# SAML 2.0 AttributeConsumingService from B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, nemlogin

I'm creating a SAML 2.0 Service Provider.
The IDP i'm connecting to requires an AttributeConsumingService with the parameters listed below in the metadata:

```
<AttributeConsumingService index="0" isDefault="true">
   <ServiceName xml:lang="da">MyServiceName</ServiceName>
   <RequestedAttribute Name="https://data.gov.dk/model/core/specVersion" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" isRequired="true" />
   <RequestedAttribute Name="https://data.gov.dk/concept/core/nsis/loa" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" isRequired="true" />
   <RequestedAttribute Name="https://data.gov.dk/model/core/eid/professional/cvr" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" isRequired="true" />
   <RequestedAttribute Name="https://data.gov.dk/model/core/eid/professional/orgName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" isRequired="true" />
</AttributeConsumingService>
```

With my current setup this is not returned in my b2c service provider metadata.

How would i go about having my B2C custom policy creating this?

My custom policy:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="NemLogin-SAML3">
   <DisplayName>NemLogin3</DisplayName>
   <Description>Login with your NemLogin3 account</Description>
   <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
   <Metadata>
      <Item Key="IssuerUri">myIssuerId</Item>
      <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://www.nemlog-in.dk/media/zrrb0a1e/oio_saml_3_test-devtest4-idp-metadata-xml.txt</Item>
      <Item Key="NameIdPolicyFormat">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</Item>
      <Item Key="ResponsesSigned">false</Item>
      <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">true</Item>
   </Metadata>
   <CryptographicKeys>
      <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_Test" />
      <Key Id="SamlAssertionDecryption" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_Test" />
   </CryptographicKeys>
   <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="assertionSubjectName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="specVersion" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="loa" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="cvr" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="orgName" Required="true" />
   </OutputClaims>
   <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml-idp" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Definition of claims in my policy:

```
<ClaimType Id="loa">
   <DisplayName>Level of assurance</DisplayName>
   <DataType>string</DataType>
   <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="loa" />
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="https://data.gov.dk/concept/core/nsis/loa" />
   </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="cvr">
   <DisplayName>Cvr</DisplayName>
   <DataType>string</DataType>
   <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="cvr" />
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="https://data.gov.dk/model/core/eid/professional/cvr" />
   </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="orgName">
   <DisplayName>Organisation Name</DisplayName>
   <DataType>string</DataType>
   <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="orgName" />
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="https://data.gov.dk/model/core/eid/professional/orgName" />
   </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="specVersion">
   <DisplayName>Spec Version</DisplayName>
   <DataType>string</DataType>
   <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="specVersion" />
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="dk:gov:saml:attribute:SpecVer" />
   </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>
```

Comment: You say that the claims aren't reflected in the metadata? Do they have to be? Are they reflected in the SAML token? Where are the claims populated?

Comment: @rbrayb The IDP requires me to upload a metadata file with an AttributeConsumingService with severeal RequestedAttribute as mentioned in the first code block. If they are not present in the metadata the IDP will not accept the metadata and i get errors suggesting that they be added.